# "The username or password is incorrect." without entering login details

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts

Usually when booting up in Windows 7, you are presented with the normal login screen.  On my computer, I am first presented with this screen:

[image: The user name or password is incorrect.]

After clicking OK, I can login with my correct login credentials and the system lets me log in fine.

At first I thought this may be because it was left idle and it auto-logged-on, however when watching my computer boot, you see this screen immediately after loading has finished.

Comment: Surprisingly, I now have this problem on Windows 10. I hope this issue will be fixed eventually.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The computer must be trying to log on with some details it has saved before it gives you a chance to login.

1. Run `netplwiz` either via the Start Menu or the Run Dialog (<kbd>[image: Win]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
   [image: Run Dialog - netplwiz]
2. Uncheck the box that says "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer." and click "Apply" and then "OK".
   [image: netplwiz]

---

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows-7/99d4fe75-3f22-499b-85fc-c7a2c4f728af

Comment: When this happened to me, I ran netplwiz and found that the "users must enter a user name..." box was already unchecked! So I checked it, clicked 'apply', then unchecked it. I then asked for a password (???), and, as I didn't want one, I left the fields blank and clicked 'OK'. Now it's OK!

Answer (score -1):

Just hit the "Reset Password" button

Comment: I can't find that button.  Is it the one directly below the spacebar?

Comment: Hello, welcome to superuser, if you could when answering a question add detail giving information for the OP to work from.